# FabCar Sample on Hyperledger Fabric

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I have successfully run sample of fab car on Hyper ledger Fabric and called sample transaction of Change Ownership of car in couch DB i m seeing only changed value coming in couchDB as I read many thread and understand its a State database but I want to know how block chain is working in Fab Car and How Previous history are in Blockchain if I want to show on UI how can i get it by writing chain code

Answer (score 0):

You are correct, the previous history of a Key is stored on the Blockchain.  the previous historical values for the key can be found using the getHistoryForKey function.

Details for [Javascript Chaincode](https://fabric-shim.github.io/release-1.4/fabric-shim.ChaincodeStub.html#getHistoryForKey__anchor) (smart contract) implementation.

Details for [Go Chaincode](https://godoc.org/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/chaincode/shim#ChaincodeStub.GetHistoryForKey) (smart contract) implementation.